# Stack Exchange API - getting answers for the questions object

Tags: rest, stackexchange-api

I use https://api.stackexchange.com/docs. To get a sample question, I use the address `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow`. Thanks to this, he gains a question. The following page shows https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question that with the default filter, the question will not have a body. I know I use a filter to get a body `filter=withbody` that is, the address comes out

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody
```

Now I would like to get answers to the question. That's why I want to use a filter `filter=withanswers`. This address

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow&filter=withanswers
```

returns an error

```
{
  "error_id": 400,
  "error_message": "Invalid filter specified",
  "error_name": "bad_parameter"
}
```

How to get answers or comments using a filter?

Answer (score 3):

I think that 2 patterns can be thought for your solution. One is a method using custom filter. Another is a method using the endpoint for retrieving answers.

### Pattern 1 :

You can create a custom filter for retrieving answers and answer's body using the endpoint of `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/### questionId ###`.

1. You can create the custom filters at http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter.

   - In your case, you can use [this](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter#include=question.answers%3Banswer.body%3Bquestion.body&base=default&unsafe=false&filter=default&run=true).

     - `question.answers;answer.body;question.body` was used as including filters.
     - The delimiter is `;`.
   - As a result, you retrieve `"filter": "!T*hPNRA69ofM1izkPP"`.
   - When you use the filter, please do URL encode it.

     - `!T*hPNRA69ofM1izkPP` becomes `%21T%2ahPNRA69ofM1izkPP`.
2. You can retrieve answers and answer's body using the endpoint.

   - When the question ID of your question is used, it's `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow&filter=%21T%2ahPNRA69ofM1izkPP`.

#### Result of pattern 1

When you can access to https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow&filter=%21T%2ahPNRA69ofM1izkPP, you can get answers and answer's body.

### Pattern 2 :

As the endpoint for retrieving answers, you can use [`/questions/{ids}/answers`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions). If the question ID is `6827752` in your question, the endpoint is as follows. In this case, in order to retrieve answer's body, `filter=withbody` is used.

#### Result of pattern 2

- When you can access to https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody, you can get answer's body.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.